# res.json sending old data

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, express

Hi I have an issue that I can't really explain with res.json from express.

Here is my /login route:

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.user) {
        var newUser = (typeof req.body.user === 'string') ? JSON.parse(req.body.user) : req.body.user;

        User.findOne({ email: newUser.email })
        .exec(function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ error: true, data: err });
            } else {
                if (user !== undefined && user !== null) {

                    // Check password and generate a token if it exist
                    encrypt.checkHash(newUser.pwd, user.pwd, function (err, isCorrect) {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.json({ error: true, data: err });
                        } else {
                            if (isCorrect != false) {

                                // Generate token and send it
                                Token.generateToken({
                                    _id: user._id, email: user.email,
                                    iat: moment().valueOf(),
                                    exp: moment().add(30, 'minutes').valueOf(),
                                },
                                conf.secret,
                                {},
                                function (err, token) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        return res.json({ error: true, authenticate: false, data: err });
                                    } else {
                                        console.log('Logged');
                                        return res.json({
                                            error: false,
                                            token: token,
                                            authenticate: true,
                                            msg: 'user_connected',
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                console.log('Not logged');
                                return res.json({ error: true, authenticate: false, msg: 'user_undefined' });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    return res.json({ error: true, authenticate: false, msg: 'user_undefined' });
               }
           }
       });
   } else {
        return res.json({ error: true, authenticate: false, msg: 'user_empty' });
   }
```

});

And here the function where I made my request to that route:

```
userRequest.auth = function (user) {
    console.log('AUTH userRequest ', user);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url + '/auth/login',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        data: { user: user },
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $log.warn('user request', response);
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }, function errorCallback(err) {

        deferred.reject(err);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

And here my onClick function which start the process

```
var promise = userRequest.auth($scope.user);

promise.then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data;
    $log.info('Login RESPONSE ', response);

    if (data.error == false && data.authenticate == true) {
        $log.info('You are logged');
        $scope.notification = setAlertBoxOptions($scope.notification, true, 'alert-success', 'Vous êtes maintenant connecté');
     } else {
         $log.info('Wrong informations');
         $scope.notification = setAlertBoxOptions($scope.notification, true, 'alert-danger', 'Utilisateur inconnue');
     }
 }, function (reason) {

    $log.error(reason);
 });
```

My function's encrypt.checkHash callback work and the value isCorrect is the good one when checking my password hash. It log 'Logged' if the password is correct and 'Not logged' if it's not.

The first time I made a request on this route it send me back an response by res.json and I get the expected data.

But after the first request, the data I receive is always the one I received on the first query.

e.g: The first time I send correct identification info and it return me

```
{error: false, token: token, authenticate: true, msg: 'user_connected'}
```

but after that, every time I try to make another query on that route I keep receiving this JSON object event if my identification info are false.

I'm not an expert in Nodejs and I tried to replace all my

```
res.json({...})
```

by

```
return res.json({...})
```

to stop the execution but the result still the same.

Can you share your wisdom with me and help me solve this case please ?

Comment: What HTTP status code is the server sending when you do this? 200 or something else?

Comment: The HTTP status code is 200, I just found out why the data isn't updated but not why it has this behavior. It is about the order the methods are executed.

The first time it is executed my userRequest.auth function is executed first and I get to the route code.

But all the other time the route code is executed first and after the userRequest.auth code.

Why is that ? Does my promise implementation is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it was happening, in my angularJS factory I initialize only once the $q service and where using it inside a method of the factory. like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory(
    'userRequest',
    ['$log', '$q',
    function ($log, $q) {

        // Initialized wrongly
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        userRequest.auth = function (user) {

            console.log('AUTH userRequest ', user);
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url + '/auth/login',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                data: { user: user },
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $log.warn('user request', response);
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function errorCallback(err) {

                deferred.reject(err);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
}])
```

instead of:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory(
    'userRequest',
    ['$log', '$q',
    function ($log, $q) {

        userRequest.auth = function (user) {

            // Where to initialize it
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            console.log('AUTH userRequest ', user);
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url + '/auth/login',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                data: { user: user },
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $log.warn('user request', response);
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function errorCallback(err) {

                deferred.reject(err);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
}])
```